# Какие существуют способы миграции данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Допустим, есть 2 сервера и нужно что-то передать по расписания с одного сервера на другой и сгенерировать почтовое сообщение.

Варианты, которые мне известны:

1)Как вариант, можно воспользоваться SSIS пакетом, но проблема в том, что при каких-либо изменениях нужно запускать тяжелую IDE-VISUAL STUDIO.

2)Написать какую-нибудь простенькую программу на C# и поставить ее в распасание на сервере. Недостаток как и у первого пункта... На коленке никаких право не сделаешь. Нужно запускать IDE и перекомпилировать прогу.

3)Линкануть сервера.

В принципе-это частично решит проблему, однако, почту я отослать не смогу.

Какие еще существуют способы?

Comment: Что Вам нужно на самом деле называется репликацией. И у каждого производителя СУБД свои годные для их СУБД инструменты. Могут быть решения репликации и между разнородными СУБД.

Comment: Простенькую программку C# можно редактировать в любом легковесном текстовом редакторе, наподобие Notepad. И компилировать с помощью [csc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78f4aasd.aspx).